# How do I get rid of the quotes and parentheses in my output?

Tags: python-3.x, inner-classes

Here is the code: I am supposed to make the code print out the area of the shapes. That part does work. But in the output there are the parentheses, quotation marks, and commas. How do I get rid of these pieces to make the output more clean?

```
import math
#adding parent class
class Shape:
    def __init__(self, X, Y):
        self.X = X
        self.Y = Y
#adding child classes and methods
class Circle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, X, Y):
        super().__init__(X, Y)
        self.X = X
        self.Y = Y

    def Area(self):
        return 'Circle with radius', self.X, 'has an area of', math.pi * self.X**2

class Rectangle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, X ,Y):
        super().__init__(X, Y)
        self.X = X
        self.Y = Y

    def Area(self):
        return 'Rectangle with a width of', self.X, 'and a height of', self.Y, 'has an area of', self.X * self.Y

class Triangle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, X, Y):
        super().__init__(X, Y)
        self.X = X
        self.Y = Y

    def Area(self):
        return 'Triangle with a base of', self.X, 'and a vertical height of', self.Y, 'has an area of', 0.5 * self.X * self.Y

class Trapezoid(Shape):
    def __init__(self, X, Y, Z):
        super().__init__(X, Y)
        self.X = X
        self.Y = Y
        self.Z = Z

    def Area(self):
        return 'Trapezoid with a long width of', self.X, 'and a short width of', self.Z, 'and a vertical height of', self.Y, 'has an area of', (0.5 * (self.Z + self.X)) * self.Y

if __name__ == '__main__':
#Main information
    c = Circle(5, 0)
    r = Rectangle(3, 4)
    t = Triangle(6, 2.7)
    tr = Trapezoid(7, 8, 4)
#Printing the output
    print(c.Area())
    print(r.Area())
    print(t.Area())
    print(tr.Area())
```

Comment: Edit your question to show the output that you are getting and what specifically you want to remove.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a tuple of strings. Instead, use f' string notation. For example:

```
    def Area(self):
        return f'Trapezoid with a long width of {self.X} and a short width of {self.Z} and a vertical height of {self.Y} has an area of {(0.5 * (self.Z + self.X)) * self.Y}'
```

Comment: Thank you! This helps so much!

Comment: My pleasure. Don’t forget to accept the answer that you find most useful by clicking on the left.

Answer (score 1):

Your functions are returning tuples, I.E a collection of values. you then print them. so you see the parenthesis to infdicate your printing a tuple, then each item is a string so its quoted, and each item in the tuple is seperated by a comma.

If your using something like python3.6 you can use f-strings to interpolate your values in the string

```
return f'Circle with radius {self.X} has an area of {math.pi * self.X**2}'
```

or you can use the format method of string

```
return 'Circle with radius {} has an area of {}'.format(self.X, math.pi * self.X**2)
```

or lastly you can convert your values to string and use the `+` value to concat the strings together.

```
return 'Circle with radius' + str(self.X) + 'has an area of ' + str(math.pi * self.X**2)
```

My preference is the first